# On extension of Monge-Ampere masses

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

It is known (evidently due to Bedford and Taylor) that if $u$ and $v$ are bounded plurisub-harmonic functions on an open domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then $$\mathbb{1}_{\{u>v\}}(dd^cu)^n = \mathbb{1}_{u>v}[dd^c\max\{u,v\}]^n$$ as Borel measures. Here $\mathbb{1}_{A}$ is the indicator function of the set $A$, and for a measure $\mu$ we denote by $\mathbb{1}_A\mu$ the trivial restriction of $\mu\Big|_A$. I am wondering whether there is a counterexample to the above equality if either $u$ or $v$ are allowed to be unbounded. In particular why isn't the above inequality always true if $v\equiv 0$? For instance I notice that in defining the so called non-pluri polar mass, most authors define it to be $$\langle (dd^c u)^n\rangle:= \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{1}_{u > -j}[dd^c\{\max u, -j\}]^n.$$ Why not simply replace the right side by $$\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{1}_{u > -j}[dd^cu]^n?$$

Comment: $(dd^c u)^n$ is not a well-defined measure on $X$

Comment: Isn't $(dd^cu)^n$ defined on $\{u>-j\}$ by the usual Bedford-Taylor theory since $u$ is bounded on that set?